# phpmyadmin default query is changed by link to table

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a problem when I select a table in phpmyadmin it automatically select the data like this

```
SELECT * FROM `admin` ORDER BY `signature_name` ASC
```

Normal it selects a table like this

```
SELECT * FROM `admin`
```

Is there a cache problem with phpmyadmin that I am facing why is it setting like that now how can I get it back to the second one at default when I click on that table in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem for specific table,

try to go on phpmyadmin home

click settings on right top side of page (not the settings icon above tree view),

main panel then browse mode and disable Remember table's sorting

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time searching for this answer and found only this answer useful. Just to update this answer: If your tables's initial default query

```
SELECT * FROM Tablename
```

has changes to another, your database remembers last sorting order. To change this behavior, in my phpmyadmin (version 4.6.6deb5) I pressed Home icon on Navigation panel -> Settings button on Main Page -> Main Panel button -> Browse Mode tab -> Unchecked Remember table's sorting checkbox.